# iOS clipsToBounds YES and Shadow?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that is kind of floating, and has rounded corners and a set height. But I want to add a shadow too it, but my problem is I need to have `clipsToBounds` turned on so my cells don't go outside of the floating UITableView.

Is there anyway to add a shadow while keeping clipsToBounds turned on for a UITableView?

Comment: Hint: `QuartzCore` framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend putting the `UITableView` within a `UIView` of the same size so you can maintain `clipsToBounds` on the `UITableView` but give that `UIView` superview the shadow so it looks as if the `UITableView` subview is casting that shadow.